# MVC Routing gives Object reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-2.1

For .NET Core 2.1 I have following routes setup;

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default_id",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

And following controller;

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Guid id = default(Guid)){
 }
```

If I access like;

```
http://localhost.example.com:5002/Users/Index/09e3eca9-6c66-09ed-701e-aa26dfab3dd2?Title=Adam
```

works fine, but following goes into error:

```
http://localhost.example.com:5002/Users/Index/
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

My setup does not resolve parameter-less Index action.

Am I missing something here?

PS: I do not want to use Controller/Action attributes. If possible I would like to resolve it in `Startup.cs`

Not an answer but while searching I found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7518

Seems like issue is resolved, but I am still getting same issue.

Comment: You first route marks the `id` parameter as option (using `/{id?}`) so your 2nd route is a bit pointless - it will never be executed

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, I noticed that. I was just trying random things to get it work, and copied pasted from that code. I will remove it.

Comment: Have you tried `Index([FromRoute] Guid? id)`. When using structs as parameters, it's much better to use nullable versions and check `.HasValue` rather than using `default(T)`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything on *ASP.Net Core* documentation, but looking at [ASP.NET Web API 2 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional) and also this [Tutorial](https://dotnetthoughts.net/attribute-routing-in-aspnet-core/), I think you need to use one of the following 2 options:

```
[Route("Home/Index/{id:Guid?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Guid id = default(Guid))
{
}

[Route("Home/Index/{id:Guid=default(Guid)}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Guid id)
{
}
```